# PHPMD - Check for duplicated code

Tags: php, duplicates, software-design, metrics, phpmd

I just found out about the tool PHPMD and I notice that it's really useful, the thing is that I read the documentation about creating custom rules and stuff, but it just talks about using software metrics from PHPDepend.

I would like to know if it's possible to implement a specific rule to check for duplicated code?

I notice that I can also use the Abstract Syntax Tree of a specific node in my custom rule, but maybe that won't help me much right?

Because to check for duplicated code I need to compare several different function/method nodes, and the apply method is called once for each node?

How could I extend PHPMD to achieve deep code analysis like this?
I wanna go far beyond software metrics..

Thank you!

Comment: [phpcpd](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd) is a better tool to search for duplicated code

Comment: right I know that, but is it possible to achieve this using PHPMD? and how? because I am doing a master thesis and I am evaluating PHPMD and need to do some extensions to it , thank you ! I am trying to avoid other tools, especially because phpcpd it has only that purpose, I am looking for generic solutions for reverse engineering purposes , thank you !

Comment: Well you're wanting to use PHPMD for something that it was never intended for; PHPMD is written specifically to report on software metrics; that's its purpose, and adding custom rules is all about software metric rules (not about unrelated functionality like copy/paste).... so there aren't really any guidelines for changing the intrinisc purpose of phpmd

Comment: Personally, I might look at options for taking the outputs from the two different toolsets and merging them into a single output

Comment: Thanks for your input @MarkBaker ! I get what you mean , make a proper answer about using the same information you gave, and I will be glad to accept it as answer ;)